# How to return all capital letters from a string in Python?

Tags: python, function, loops, conditional-statements, letters

Curious to see if there's a way to return all capital letters from a string in Python, not using is.upper, maybe using other conditionals?

Comment: Why not using `isupper`? Otherwise `return [i for i in s if i in string.ascii_uppercase`] would work

Comment: Or if you want to impress her: `re.sub('[^A-Z]', '', your_string)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `isupper` is not a function applied to a astring, but a method. That filter statement won't work.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be:

```
[char for char in _string if char.isupper()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using anything other than `list comprehension` (that too can be replaced by normal `for` loop)

```
>>> [s for s in string if 'A'<=s<='Z']
=> ['A', 'D', 'F', 'G']
```

#driver values :

```
IN : string = 'AbcDeFGh2i'
```